# Plotting multiple seaborn displot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, displot

I am trying to create distplot of a dataframe grouped by a column

```
data_plot = creditcard_df.copy()
amount = data_plot['Amount']
data_plot.drop(labels=['Amount'], axis=1, inplace = True)
data_plot.insert(0, 'Amount', amount)

# Plot the distributions of the features
columns = data_plot.iloc[:,0:30].columns
plt.figure(figsize=(12,30*4))
grids = gridspec.GridSpec(30, 1)
for grid, index in enumerate(data_plot[columns]):
    ax = plt.subplot(grids[grid])
    sns.distplot(data_plot[index][data_plot.Class == 1], hist=False, kde_kws={"shade": True}, bins=20)
    sns.distplot(data_plot[index][data_plot.Class == 0], hist=False, kde_kws={"shade": True}, bins=20)
    ax.set_xlabel("")
    ax.set_title("Distribution of Column: "  + str(index))
    plt.show()
```

[image: plot]
I tried to use a log scale for the y axis, change the gridspec, and the figsize; but all of those only made a mess of the distributions.
Is there a way to make the plots uniform?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- [`seaborn.distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) is deprecated. Use [`seaborn.kdeplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html#seaborn.kdeplot), which is an axes-level plot. Otherwise use [`seaborn.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html#seaborn.displot) for a figure-level plot.
- **Tested in `python 3.11`, `pandas 1.5.3`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

### Imports and Test Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(365)
rows = 10000
data = {'a': np.random.normal(5, 5, rows),
        'b': np.random.normal(20, 5, rows),
        'c': np.random.normal(35, 5, rows),
        'd': np.random.normal(500, 50, rows),
        'e': np.random.normal(6500, 500, rows),
        'class': np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(rows), p=[0.25, 0.75])}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# display(df.head(3))
          a          b          c           d            e  class
0  5.839606  20.807027  34.798230  509.328065  6003.228497      0
1  7.617526  21.691519  40.519995  445.724478  7204.039621      0
2  9.086878  27.193222  32.776264  498.254687  6810.960924      1
```

### Plot with `seaborn.kdeplot`

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3, figsize=(15, 7), sharex=False, sharey=False)
axes = axes.ravel()  # array to 1D
cols = df.columns[:-1]  # create a list of dataframe columns to use

for col, ax in zip(cols, axes):
    data = df[[col, 'class']]  # select the data
    sns.kdeplot(data=data, x=col, hue='class', fill=True, ax=ax)
    ax.set(title=f'Distribution of Column: {col}', xlabel=None)
    
fig.delaxes(axes[5])  # delete the empty subplot
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Plot with `seaborn.displot`

```py
# convert the dataframe from wide to long
dfm = df.melt(id_vars='class', var_name='Distribution')

# display(dfm.head(3))
   class Distribution     value
0      0            a  5.839606
1      0            a  7.617526
2      1            a  9.086878

# plot
sns.displot(kind='kde', data=dfm, col='Distribution', col_wrap=3, x='value', hue='class', fill=True, facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': False})
```

[image]