# Multiple Seaborn.kdeplot for each column of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, subplot

The goal is to create a density plot for each of the `outlier` variables within the main dataframe `df`...

```
outliers.index = ['SalePrice', 'LotArea', '2ndFlrSF', 'MasVnrArea', 'WoodDeckSF', 'BsmtUnfSF', '1stFlrSF', 'BsmtFinSF1', 'TotalBsmtSF', 'GrLivArea']
sns.distplot( df[outliers.index[0]])
```

[image]

... in the same `kdeplot` format similar to the below picture [(Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69067250/plotting-multiple-seaborn-displot), where you could line up the `outliers.index` outputs in 2 or 3 rows:
[image]

My code is currently the below and am getting a `ValueError: Could not interpret value SalePrice for parameter x` error.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3, figsize=(15, 7), sharex=False, sharey=False)
axes = axes.ravel()  # array to 1D
cols = outliers.index  # create a list of dataframe columns to use
print(cols)

for col, ax in zip(cols, axes):
    data = df[col]  # select the data
    sns.kdeplot(data=data, x=col, shade=True, ax=ax)
    ax.set(title=f'Distribution of Column: {col}', xlabel=None)
    
fig.delaxes(axes[5])  # delete the empty subplot
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Sample of main dataframe `df`:

```
{'LotFrontage': {1325: 40.0, 1252: 62.0, 487: 70.0, 1074: 74.0, 179: 60.0},
 'GarageYrBlt': {1325: 1978.9510426110608,
  1252: 1968.0,
  487: 1971.0,
  1074: 2006.0,
  179: 1935.0},
 'MasVnrArea': {1325: 0.0, 1252: 0.0, 487: 0.0, 1074: 0.0, 179: 0.0},
 'Id': {1325: 1326, 1252: 1253, 487: 488, 1074: 1075, 179: 180},
 'Functional_Mod': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Condition2_Norm': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'Condition2_Feedr': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Condition2_Artery': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Functional_Typ': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'Functional_Sev': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Functional_Min1': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Functional_Min2': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Condition2_PosN': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Functional_Maj2': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Functional_Maj1': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'SaleCondition_Partial': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'SaleCondition_Normal': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'SaleCondition_Family': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Condition2_PosA': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Condition2_RRAn': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'SaleCondition_AdjLand': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Condition2_RRNn': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'HouseStyle_1.5Fin': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'HouseStyle_1.5Unf': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'HouseStyle_1Story': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'HouseStyle_2.5Fin': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'HouseStyle_2.5Unf': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'HouseStyle_2Story': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'HouseStyle_SFoyer': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'HouseStyle_SLvl': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'SaleType_COD': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'SaleType_CWD': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'SaleType_Con': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'SaleType_ConLD': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'SaleType_ConLI': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'SaleCondition_Alloca': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BsmtFinType2_Unf': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'SaleCondition_Abnorml': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'SaleType_New': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'GarageType_2Types': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'GarageType_Attchd': {1325: 0, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 0},
 'GarageType_Basment': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'GarageType_BuiltIn': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'GarageType_CarPort': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'GarageType_Detchd': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 1},
 'Foundation_BrkTil': {1325: 1, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Foundation_CBlock': {1325: 0, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 0, 179: 1},
 'Foundation_PConc': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 1, 179: 0},
 'Foundation_Slab': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Foundation_Stone': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Foundation_Wood': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BsmtFinType1_ALQ': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 1, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BsmtFinType1_BLQ': {1325: 0, 1252: 1, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BsmtFinType1_GLQ': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BsmtFinType1_LwQ': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BsmtFinType1_Rec': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BsmtFinType1_Unf': {1325: 1, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'RoofStyle_Flat': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'RoofStyle_Gable': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'RoofStyle_Gambrel': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'RoofStyle_Hip': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'RoofStyle_Mansard': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'RoofStyle_Shed': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BsmtFinType2_ALQ': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BsmtFinType2_BLQ': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BsmtFinType2_GLQ': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BsmtFinType2_LwQ': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BsmtFinType2_Rec': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'SaleType_ConLw': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'SaleType_WD': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'SaleType_Oth': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Neighborhood_Gilbert': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior2nd_Plywood': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 1, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior2nd_Stone': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior2nd_Stucco': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior2nd_VinylSd': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 1, 179: 0},
 'Exterior2nd_Wd Sdng': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 1},
 'Exterior2nd_Wd Shng': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Neighborhood_Blmngtn': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Neighborhood_Blueste': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Neighborhood_BrDale': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Neighborhood_BrkSide': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Neighborhood_ClearCr': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Neighborhood_CollgCr': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 1, 179: 0},
 'Neighborhood_Crawfor': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Neighborhood_Edwards': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Neighborhood_IDOTRR': {1325: 1, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'FireplaceQu_Po': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Neighborhood_MeadowV': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Neighborhood_Mitchel': {1325: 0, 1252: 1, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Neighborhood_NAmes': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Neighborhood_NPkVill': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Neighborhood_NWAmes': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 1, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Neighborhood_NoRidge': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Neighborhood_NridgHt': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Neighborhood_OldTown': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 1},
 'Neighborhood_SWISU': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Neighborhood_Sawyer': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Neighborhood_SawyerW': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Neighborhood_Somerst': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Neighborhood_StoneBr': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Neighborhood_Timber': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior2nd_Other': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior2nd_MetalSd': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior2nd_ImStucc': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior2nd_HdBoard': {1325: 0, 1252: 1, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Condition1_Artery': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Condition1_Feedr': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Condition1_Norm': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'Condition1_PosA': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Condition1_PosN': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Condition1_RRAe': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Condition1_RRAn': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Condition1_RRNe': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Condition1_RRNn': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior1st_AsbShng': {1325: 1, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior1st_AsphShn': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior1st_BrkComm': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior1st_BrkFace': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior1st_CBlock': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior1st_CemntBd': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior1st_HdBoard': {1325: 0, 1252: 1, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior1st_MetalSd': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior1st_Plywood': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 1, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior1st_Stone': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior1st_Stucco': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior1st_VinylSd': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 1, 179: 0},
 'Exterior1st_Wd Sdng': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 1},
 'Exterior1st_WdShing': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior2nd_AsbShng': {1325: 1, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior2nd_AsphShn': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior2nd_Brk Cmn': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior2nd_BrkFace': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior2nd_CBlock': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Exterior2nd_CmentBd': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'FireplaceQu_TA': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 1, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'FireplaceQu_Fa': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'FireplaceQu_Gd': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'GarageFinish_Unf': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 1, 1074: 0, 179: 1},
 'Street_Grvl': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Street_Pave': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'Utilities_AllPub': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'Utilities_NoSeWa': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'CentralAir_N': {1325: 1, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'CentralAir_Y': {1325: 0, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'LandSlope_Gtl': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'LandSlope_Mod': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'LandSlope_Sev': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'PavedDrive_N': {1325: 1, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 1},
 'PavedDrive_P': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'PavedDrive_Y': {1325: 0, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 0},
 'GarageFinish_Fin': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'GarageFinish_RFn': {1325: 0, 1252: 1, 487: 0, 1074: 1, 179: 0},
 'BsmtExposure_Av': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 0},
 'ExterQual_Ex': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BsmtExposure_Gd': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BsmtExposure_Mn': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BsmtExposure_No': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 1},
 'KitchenQual_Ex': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'KitchenQual_Fa': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'KitchenQual_Gd': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 1, 179: 0},
 'KitchenQual_TA': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 0, 179: 1},
 'HeatingQC_Ex': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 1, 179: 0},
 'HeatingQC_Fa': {1325: 1, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'HeatingQC_Gd': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 1, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'HeatingQC_TA': {1325: 0, 1252: 1, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 1},
 'BsmtQual_Ex': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BsmtQual_Fa': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BsmtQual_Gd': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 0},
 'SalePrice': {1325: 55000,
  1252: 130000,
  487: 175000,
  1074: 194000,
  179: 100000},
 'YrSold': {1325: 2008, 1252: 2009, 487: 2007, 1074: 2007, 179: 2007},
 'MoSold': {1325: 1, 1252: 11, 487: 2, 1074: 5, 179: 7},
 'MiscVal': {1325: 0, 1252: 600, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'LotArea': {1325: 3636, 1252: 9858, 487: 12243, 1074: 8556, 179: 8520},
 'OverallQual': {1325: 4, 1252: 5, 487: 5, 1074: 7, 179: 5},
 'OverallCond': {1325: 4, 1252: 6, 487: 6, 1074: 5, 179: 6},
 'YearBuilt': {1325: 1922, 1252: 1968, 487: 1971, 1074: 2006, 179: 1923},
 'YearRemodAdd': {1325: 1950, 1252: 1968, 487: 1971, 1074: 2006, 179: 2006},
 'BsmtFinSF1': {1325: 0, 1252: 510, 487: 998, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BsmtFinSF2': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BsmtUnfSF': {1325: 796, 1252: 354, 487: 486, 1074: 1240, 179: 968},
 'TotalBsmtSF': {1325: 796, 1252: 864, 487: 1484, 1074: 1240, 179: 968},
 '1stFlrSF': {1325: 796, 1252: 874, 487: 1484, 1074: 1240, 179: 968},
 '2ndFlrSF': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'LowQualFinSF': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'GrLivArea': {1325: 796, 1252: 874, 487: 1484, 1074: 1240, 179: 968},
 'BsmtFullBath': {1325: 0, 1252: 1, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BsmtHalfBath': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'FullBath': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 2, 1074: 2, 179: 1},
 'HalfBath': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BedroomAbvGr': {1325: 2, 1252: 3, 487: 3, 1074: 2, 179: 2},
 'KitchenAbvGr': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'TotRmsAbvGrd': {1325: 5, 1252: 5, 487: 7, 1074: 5, 179: 5},
 'Fireplaces': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 1, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'GarageCars': {1325: 0, 1252: 1, 487: 2, 1074: 3, 179: 2},
 'GarageArea': {1325: 0, 1252: 288, 487: 487, 1074: 826, 179: 480},
 'WoodDeckSF': {1325: 0, 1252: 33, 487: 224, 1074: 140, 179: 0},
 'OpenPorchSF': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 93, 179: 0},
 'EnclosedPorch': {1325: 100, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 184},
 '3SsnPorch': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'ScreenPorch': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 180, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'PoolArea': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BsmtQual_TA': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 1},
 'ExterQual_Fa': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'MSSubClass': {1325: 30, 1252: 20, 487: 20, 1074: 20, 179: 30},
 'GarageQual_Ex': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Heating_GasW': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Heating_Grav': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Heating_OthW': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Heating_Wall': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'RoofMatl_CompShg': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'RoofMatl_Roll': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'RoofMatl_Tar&Grv': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'RoofMatl_WdShake': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'RoofMatl_WdShngl': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BldgType_1Fam': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'BldgType_2fmCon': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BldgType_Duplex': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BldgType_Twnhs': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BldgType_TwnhsE': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'GarageQual_Fa': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 1},
 'ExterQual_Gd': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'GarageQual_Gd': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'GarageQual_Po': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'GarageQual_TA': {1325: 0, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 0},
 'GarageCond_Ex': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'GarageCond_Fa': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'GarageCond_Gd': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'GarageCond_Po': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'GarageCond_TA': {1325: 0, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'LotConfig_Corner': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'LotConfig_CulDSac': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'LotConfig_FR2': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'LotConfig_FR3': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'LotConfig_Inside': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'FireplaceQu_Ex': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Heating_GasA': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'MSZoning_RM': {1325: 1, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 1},
 'MSZoning_RL': {1325: 0, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 0},
 'MSZoning_RH': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'ExterQual_TA': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'MasVnrType_BrkCmn': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'MasVnrType_BrkFace': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'MasVnrType_None': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'MasVnrType_Stone': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'LandContour_Bnk': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'LandContour_HLS': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'LandContour_Low': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'LandContour_Lvl': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'LotShape_IR1': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 1, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'LotShape_IR2': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'LotShape_IR3': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'LotShape_Reg': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 0, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'BsmtCond_Fa': {1325: 1, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BsmtCond_Gd': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BsmtCond_Po': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'BsmtCond_TA': {1325: 0, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'Electrical_FuseA': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Electrical_FuseF': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Electrical_FuseP': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Electrical_Mix': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Electrical_SBrkr': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'ExterCond_Ex': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'ExterCond_Fa': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'ExterCond_Gd': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'ExterCond_Po': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'ExterCond_TA': {1325: 1, 1252: 1, 487: 1, 1074: 1, 179: 1},
 'MSZoning_C (all)': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'MSZoning_FV': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0},
 'Neighborhood_Veenker': {1325: 0, 1252: 0, 487: 0, 1074: 0, 179: 0}}
```

Comment: What do you want to plot in each subplot?

Comment: @QuangHoang Great point! Updated the entire question.

Comment: Add main dataframe `df` sample code too.